# SpringBootTest failing with 'IllegalStateException - No ServletContext set'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, shedlock

I have a pretty simple `@SpringBootTest` :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {...})
public class MyApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void anyTest() { ... }
}
```

It was working as expected until we've added `@EnableSchedulerLock` (from [Shedlock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)) on the `MyApplication.java`  file.

Since, we're experiencing this issue :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:483)
```

This happends when Spring tries to instanciate its `resourceHandlerMapping` :

```
@Bean
public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
    Assert.state(this.applicationContext != null, "No ApplicationContext set");
    Assert.state(this.servletContext != null, "No ServletContext set");
    ...
```

It's like this `@Bean` is created before the `setServletContext` (from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`) is called.

Comment: Hi, which ShedLock version do you use? It should not happen in the latest one. It's also possible that there is another exception which is the root cause.

Comment: We were using 2.2.0, I've tried to upgrade it to 2.5.0 and, as you said, there is no more exception. Thanks. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Lukas, this error has been fixed in the latest version of Shedlock.

**Upgrading Shedlock's version** from `2.2.0` to `2.5.0` fixes the issue.